# Need help in getting mysql event scheduled every monday and wednesday

Tags: mysql, jobs, event

I have coded an event as below to run every Monday and Wednesday, but it runs only on Monday and doesn't on Wednesday.

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS evnt_demo_ref_fs_test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE enable
DO 
   BEGIN
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';
    
DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        /*errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;*/
        @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE  , @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT;
        INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) SELECT CONCAT('ERR_CODE: ', @p1) AS STATUS, CONCAT('MySQL ERROR: ', @p1, ': ', @p2) AS MESSAGE;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    /*IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 5 and 7 THEN */
    IF WEEKDAY(curdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','demo refresh started');
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','Deletes started');
delete from drop_curr_fs;
delete from drop_hist_fs;
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','Deletes Completed');
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','Inserts Started');
insert into drop_curr_fs select  * From     master  ;
insert into drop_hist_fs select  * From     hist_master ;
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','Inserts Completed');
INSERT INTO demo_log_fs (CODE, message) values ('0000','demo refresh Completed');
end if;
END |
delimiter ;
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: it should run from Monday **till** Wednesday, how did you determine that it didn't run on Wednesday?

Comment: Would this work ?  IF WEEKDAY(curdate()) EQUAL 0 OR 2 THEN

    rather than BETWEEN?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the KISS design principle:

1. Write a Stored Procedure that does most of the work.
2. Fire that SP from 2 events, one each Monday, one each Wed.

Note that all the timing (Mon/Wed) information is in the Event; none is in the SP.  Nice and clean separation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time on this.

I figured out the solution.  The issue was with the BETWEEN keyword, that triggers the event between the mentioned dates.  So I changed it to IN keyword and it worked fine.

Thank you,
Mushtaq Ahmed B